# Google login Integration UI simulator issue iOS 13 Xode 11

Tags: google-authentication, ios13, xcode11

I am authenticating user via google login. Whenever i open gmail login window after clicking on login button i can't add login credentials in text Field on simulator because keyboard is not appearing Also user interaction getting disable whenever click on textfield. ? Any one know what is the exact issue?

[image]

Comment: can you share your code which presents the screen you attached?

Comment: Hi Shahbaz Akram . can you get the answer for this issue